# How can I get ColdFusion methods to return numeric values as strings in JSON format?

Tags: json, coldfusion, user-defined-functions

ColdFusion 8

This is as simple pseudo-code as there can be:

```
<cffunction name="badJSON" access="remote" output="true" returntype="string" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfreturn "06762" />
</cffunction>
```

Results in:

```
6762.0
```

It should result in:

```
06762
```

Is there a way to get JSON to not convert my value to numeric?

I know I can use WDDX, but that is out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so there is no *real* way to do this in CF8. The workaround is to add a character to the beginning or end of the string, and then handle it in the client side code. I'm working with USA ZIP Codes, so it was simply a matter of formatting each ZIP as ZIP+4 (00000-0000). That little dash in there makes it a string.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

return javaCast("string", "06762")

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fixed in CF9.0.1 with Cumulative Hotfix 1... which version are you using?  If you really want `"06762"` you can try `returntype="plain"`

Comment: I think you're right that this JSON serialization issue is fixed in 9.0.1, but that's only helpful if he is using CF9. If using CF8, see Rick O's answer about JavaCast -- that should work on CF8.

Comment: Yes, I hread it was fixed in CF9. The website I am working on is currently CF8.

Comment: This is not fixed... even in CF10, at least when trying to call a remote function from a CFC in returnFormat="json". In Javascript, I'm testing for the type of object like this: if ((typeof(item.postalCode) === 'string' && item.postalCode.length) || (typeof(item.postalCode) === 'number' && item.postalCode > 0)) {}