# Why does SerializeJSON return an int with .0?

Tags: json, coldfusion

The following code:

```
<cfscript>
struct = StructNew();
struct.x = 1;
struct.y = 2;
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(struct)#</cfoutput>
```

Results in the following output:

```
{"Y":2.0,"X":1.0}
```

So my question is why does the `.0` get added? and is there some way to remove it?

Comment: There are couple of questions discussing this already. This http://stackoverflow.com/q/3640003/56604 or this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2479737/56604 / there are few workarounds proposed, select which you like more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a trailing .0 to numbers was a known "feature" in the way serializeJson was implemented  in release 8. It is fixed/changed in CF 9.01 on my home XP machine your code returns

```
{"Y":"2","X":"1"}
```

Comment: CF9 is converting numbers to strings?!?

Answer (score 5):

The best thing I found to remove the .0 is a cast, using the Coldfusion function javaCast :

```
struct.x = javaCast("int",1);
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume the implementation is not the best :-/ try to checkout this: http://craigkaminsky.blogspot.com/2008/11/coldfusion-serializejson-gotcha.html

Answer (score -1):

Two ways to remove it:

```
NumberFormat(x, "9")
```

`<cfset x = 1.0>
<cfset y = x * 1> <!--- will convert to an int --->`

Comment: both methods don't do what I want.

Comment: ah, they would both work on the values in the JSON struct AFTER the serialization, but not if you applied them to the numbers in your original struct.  I guess that's what you really wanted, as you might be passing the JSON to javascript or whatever which wouldn't have access to these CFML methods.